# Send an uploaded file to client with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new with node.js.
Here is my problem: I upload a file from html

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"
   <div>
      <input type="file" name="myFile" id="fileUpload" multiple />
    </div>
     <div>
      <input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

then I upload the file from directory with multer and parse with the npm pdfParser from pdf to json, the files are regularly copied in the main directory and the code goes back to home page.

```
try {
  app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (req.file == undefined) {
          res.redirect("index.html");
        } else {
          fileOriginale = req.file.originalname;
          const pdfParser = new PDFParser();
          pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", (errData) =>
            console.error(errData.parserError)
          );
          pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", (pdfData) => {
            const test = fileOriginale.substring(0, fileOriginale.length - 4);
            const id = __dirname + "/" + test + ".json";
            console.log("filetofetch in pdfParser", id);
            fs.writeFile(
              id,
              JSON.stringify(pdfData),
              (err) => console.error(err)
            );
          });
          pdfParser.loadPDF(__dirname + "/" + fileOriginale.toString());
          res.redirect("index.html");
          res.end();
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return;
}
```

Here the issue: How can I parse the .json file loaded in the main directory and send it to the client ?

Comment: Looks like your code is parsing the PDF then redirecting the client to index.html. Did you try `res.json(pdfData)` to send a JSON response instead of the redirect/end?

Comment: @jarmod thanks for your reply. I tried and send the json. But I return on http://localhost:3000/upload page and stick there. How can then go to client index.htlm page and getting data from the json file ?

Comment: Why is it a problem to stay on the upload url afterward? The other option I see is to redirect the user to index and to pass a document id, but you will have to implement a new route on your server to retrieve the document from the id.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin Thanks. If I stay in upload url I don't know how to send the data to index.html. How can I do it ?